# CharacterController velocity flickering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Spine.Unity;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region components
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Animator animator;
    private LedgeGrabber grabber;
    private SkeletonAnimator skelAnim;
    private GameObject root;
    #endregion

    #region movement
    //[HideInInspector]
    public Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    private float gravity = -100f;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float walkSpeed = 20;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float runSpeed = 40;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float curSpd;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float airControlPercent;
    private float speedSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    private float speedSmoothVelocity;
    public bool onGround = false;
    #endregion

    #region jumps
    private float jumpHeight = 10f;
    public bool canJump = false;
    private float timer = .5f;
    public bool landing = false;
    public bool canLeap = false;
    #endregion

    #region animation
    private float animSpdPer;
    private AnimatorStateInfo info;
    #endregion

    #region slope and wall
    private float slopeAngle;
    public bool maxSlope = false;
    public bool normSlope = false;
    private Vector3 slopeNormal;
    public bool wallSliding = false;
    private float wallSlideSpdMax = 16f;
    private int dirX;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int wallDir;
    public Vector2 jumpOff = Vector2.zero;
    public Vector2 wallLeap = Vector2.zero;
    #endregion

    #region platform
    [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject platform;
    #endregion
    [Header("Ledge data intake")]
    #region Ledge data
    public GameObject ledge;
    public BoxCollider targetLedge;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Vector3 ledgePos = Vector3.zero;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool stallMovement = false;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool climbingNow = false;
    #endregion
    [Space(50)]

    public float _timer = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        grabber = GetComponentInChildren<LedgeGrabber>();
        skelAnim = GetComponent<SkeletonAnimator>();
        root = GameObject.Find("root");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ApplyAnimatorParam();
        ResetAnimatorParam();
        GrabberListener();

        Move();
        JumpGate();
        ResetTimer();
    }

    void Move()
    {
        if (!stallMovement)
        {
            if (controller.isGrounded)
            {
                if (!maxSlope && !normSlope)
                {
                    velocity = GroundVelocity(ref velocity);
                    onGround = true;

                    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
                    {
                        Jump();
                        onGround = false;
                    }
                }
                if (maxSlope)
                {
                    velocity = MaxSlopeVelocity(ref velocity);
                    onGround = true;
                }
                if (normSlope)
                {
                    velocity = NormSlopeVelocity(ref velocity);
                    onGround = true;
                    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
                    {
                        Jump();
                        canJump = false;
                        onGround = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (wallSliding)
            {
                WallSlideVelocity(ref velocity);
                onGround = false;
            }

            ApplyGravity();

            controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        FaceDir();
    }

    void TimeIt()
    {
        _timer += 1 * Time.deltaTime;

        if (_timer >= 1.2f)
        {
            canLeap = true;
        }
        else
            canLeap = false;
    }

    void ResetTimer()
    {
        if (_timer != 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                _timer = 0;
            }
        }
    } 

    Vector3 GroundVelocity(ref Vector3 vel)
    {
        bool running = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && controller.isGrounded;
        Vector2 input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0);
        Vector2 inputDir = input.normalized;
        float targetSpeed = ((running) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * inputDir.magnitude;
        curSpd = Mathf.SmoothDamp(curSpd, targetSpeed, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime * 3));
        animSpdPer = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, curSpd);
        vel = new Vector3(curSpd, 0, 0);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            return vel;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            return -vel;
        }

        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    Vector3 MaxSlopeVelocity(ref Vector3 vel)
    {
        float velY = velocity.y + slopeNormal.y * gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        float velX = Mathf.Sign(slopeNormal.x) * (Mathf.Abs(velY / 2) / Mathf.Tan(slopeAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad));

        if (dirX == 1)
        {
            #region leap ready
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                if (_timer <= 1.2f)
                {
                    TimeIt();
                }
                velY = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velY, 0f, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));
                velX = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velX, 0f, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));
                animator.SetBool("leapRdy", true);
                root.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            }
            #endregion

            #region leap
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                if (canLeap)
                {
                    LeapOnUp(ref velocity);
                    animator.SetBool("leapRdy", false);
                    animator.SetBool("leap", true);
                }
            } 
            #endregion
            else
            vel =  new Vector3(velX, velY, 0);
        }
        if (dirX == -1)
        {
            #region leap ready
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                if (_timer <= 1.2f)
                {
                    TimeIt();
                }
                velY = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velY, 0f, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));
                velX = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velX, 0f, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));
                animator.SetBool("leapRdy", true);
                root.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            }
            #endregion

            #region leap
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                if (canLeap)
                {
                    LeapOnUp(ref velocity);
                    animator.SetBool("leapRdy", false);
                    animator.SetBool("leap", true);
                }
            } 
            #endregion
            else
            vel =  new Vector3(-velX, velY, 0);
        }
        return vel;
    }

    Vector3 NormSlopeVelocity(ref Vector3 vel)
    {
        bool running = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && controller.isGrounded;
        Vector2 input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0);
        Vector2 inputDir = input.normalized;
        float targetSpeed = ((running) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * inputDir.magnitude;
        curSpd = Mathf.SmoothDamp(curSpd, targetSpeed, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));
        float moveDist = Mathf.Abs(curSpd);

        float velX = Mathf.Cos(slopeAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * moveDist * Mathf.Sign(curSpd);
        float velY = Mathf.Sin(slopeAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * moveDist;

        vel = new Vector3(velX, velY, 0);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            return vel;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            return -vel;
        }

        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    Vector3 WallSlideVelocity(ref Vector3 vel)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            WallJumpOff(ref velocity);
            animator.SetBool("jumped", true);
            animator.SetBool("wallSlide", false);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (_timer <= 1.2f)
            {
                TimeIt(); 
            }

            wallSlideSpdMax -= _timer * 10;
            animator.SetBool("leapRdy", true);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (canLeap)
            {
                LeapOnUp(ref velocity);
                animator.SetBool("leap", true); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            vel.y = -wallSlideSpdMax;
            vel.x = 0;
            wallSlideSpdMax = 16f;
        }

        return vel;
    }

    Vector3 LeapOnUp(ref Vector3 vel)
    {
        if (canLeap)
        {
            #region on wall
            if (wallSliding)
            {
                wallSliding = false;
                maxSlope = false;
                if (wallDir == 1)
                {
                    vel.y = Mathf.Abs(wallLeap.y);
                    vel.x = -wallDir * wallLeap.x;
                }
                if (wallDir == -1)
                {
                    vel.y = Mathf.Abs(wallLeap.y);
                    vel.x = -wallDir * wallLeap.x;
                }
                wallSlideSpdMax = 16f;
                animator.SetBool("leapRdy", false);
                animator.SetBool("wallSlide", false);
            }
            #endregion

            #region on max slope
            if (maxSlope)
            {
                maxSlope = false;
                if (dirX == 1)
                {
                    vel.y = Mathf.Abs(wallLeap.y);
                    vel.x = dirX * wallLeap.x;
                }
                if (dirX == -1)
                {
                    vel.y = Mathf.Abs(wallLeap.y);
                    vel.x = dirX * wallLeap.x;
                }
                animator.SetBool("leapRdy", false);
                canLeap = false;
            }
            #endregion 
        }

        return vel;
    }

    float GetModifiedSmoothTime(float smoothTime)
    {
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            return smoothTime;
        }

        if (airControlPercent == 0)
        {
            return float.MaxValue;
        }

        return smoothTime / airControlPercent;
    }

    void FaceDir()
    {
        #region on ground, jump and fall
        if (!wallSliding && !maxSlope)
        {
            if (velocity.x > 0)
            {
                transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            }
            if (velocity.x < 0)
            {
                transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
            }
        } 
        #endregion

        #region on wall slide
        if (wallSliding)
        {
            if (!controller.isGrounded)
            {
                if (wallDir == -1)
                {
                    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
                }
                if (wallDir == 1)
                {
                    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        } 
        #endregion

        #region on max slope
        if (maxSlope)
        {
            if (dirX == 1)
            {
                controller.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
                root.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, slopeAngle);
            }
            if (dirX == -1)
            {
                controller.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                root.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -slopeAngle);
            }
            if (animator.GetBool("leapRdy") == true)
            {
                root.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            }
        } 
        #endregion
    }

    void ApplyGravity()
    {
        if (!controller.isGrounded || maxSlope || !wallSliding)
        {
            velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            if (velocity.y <= -5f)
            {
                onGround = false; // here onGround conflicts and flickers 
            }
        }
        else
            velocity.y = 0;
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (canJump)
        {
            float jumpVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(-2 * gravity * jumpHeight);
            velocity.y = jumpVelocity;
            animator.SetBool("jumped", true);
            slopeAngle = 0;
            maxSlope = false;
            normSlope = false;
            transform.parent = null;
            landing = false;
            animator.SetBool("onGround", false);
        }
    }

    void JumpGate()
    {
        #region check landing
        if (!maxSlope && transform.parent == null)
        {
            if (velocity.y < -2f)
            {
                float rayLength = 7f;
                Ray landingCheck = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);
                RaycastHit hit; // = new RaycastHit();

                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, -Vector3.up * rayLength);

                if (Physics.Raycast(landingCheck, out hit, rayLength))
                {
                    //if (Mathf.Abs(hit.normal.x) <= Mathf.Abs(slopeNormal.x))
                    if(Mathf.Abs(hit.collider.transform.localEulerAngles.z) <= controller.slopeLimit)
                    {
                        if (animator.GetBool("onGround") == false)
                        {
                            landing = true;
                            animator.SetBool("landing", true);
                            canJump = false;
                            Invoke("ResetJump", .3f);
                            animator.SetBool("onGround", true); 
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    animator.SetBool("onGround", false); 
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region gate time between jumps

        #endregion
    }

    void ResetJump()
    {
        landing = false;
        animator.SetBool("landing", false);
        animator.SetBool("onGround", true);
        canJump = true;
    }

    void WallJumpOff(ref Vector3 vel)
    {
        wallSliding = false;
        if (wallDir == 1)
        {
            vel.y = velocity.y + Mathf.Abs(velocity.y + jumpHeight);
            vel.x = velocity.x + -wallDir * jumpOff.x;
            controller.Move(vel * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (wallDir == -1)
        {
            vel.y = velocity.y + Mathf.Abs(velocity.y + jumpHeight);
            vel.x = velocity.x + -wallDir * jumpOff.x;
            controller.Move(vel * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void GrabberListener()
    {
        // LedgeGrabber.cs should output some data and this will take it to pass to some others
        if (grabber.targetLedge != null && grabber.ledge != null)
        {
            if (grabber.normalLedge ^ grabber.platLedge)
            {
                ledge = grabber.ledge;
                targetLedge = grabber.targetLedge;
                ledgePos = grabber.ledgePos;
                GetModY();
                //animator.SetTrigger("onLedge"); // this is only place where sets onLedge parameter to true 
            }
        }
        if (grabber.targetLedge == null)
        {
            ledge = null;
            targetLedge = null;
        }
    }

    private void climbStart(int value = 1)
    {
        animator.SetBool("climbing", true);
        climbingNow = true;

        if (grabber.normalLedge)
        {
            stallMovement = true;
        }
        if (grabber.platLedge)
        {
            stallMovement = true;
            transform.parent = ledge.transform;
        }
    }

    private void climbEnd(int value = 1)
    {
        float modX = 3f;

        #region climb normal ledge
        if (grabber.normalLedge)
        {
            Vector3 climb = new Vector3(ledgePos.x - (-modX * 1.5f), transform.position.y + GetModY(), transform.position.z);

            GetComponent<Transform>().position = climb;
        }
        #endregion

        #region climb platform ledge
        if (grabber.platLedge)
        {
            float oldX = transform.position.x;
            transform.parent = ledge.transform;

            Vector3 climbR = new Vector3(oldX - (-modX), transform.position.y + GetModY(), transform.position.z);
            Vector3 climbL = new Vector3(oldX - (modX), transform.position.y + GetModY(), transform.position.z);

            if (ledgePos.x > transform.position.x)
            {
                GetComponent<Transform>().position = climbR;
            }
            else
            {
                GetComponent<Transform>().position = climbL;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        stallMovement = false;
        animator.SetBool("climbing", false);
        climbingNow = false;
        animator.SetBool("onGround", true);
        canJump = true;
    }

    //private void StallPlayer()
    //{
    //    // this will stall Player's movement or parent it if it's a mobile platform
    //    if (grabber.normalLedge)
    //    {
    //        stallMovement = true;
    //    }
    //    if (grabber.platLedge)
    //    {
    //        stallMovement = true;
    //        transform.parent = ledge.transform;
    //    }
    //}

    //private void MovePlayerOnLedge()
    //{
    //    // this will actually move player
    //    float modX = 3f;

    //    #region climb normal ledge
    //    if (grabber.normalLedge)
    //    {
    //        Vector3 climb = new Vector3(ledgePos.x - (-modX * 1.5f), transform.position.y + GetModY(), transform.position.z);

    //        GetComponent<Transform>().position = climb;
    //    } 
    //    #endregion

    //    #region climb platform ledge
    //    if (grabber.platLedge)
    //    {
    //        float oldX = transform.position.x;
    //        transform.parent = ledge.transform;

    //        Vector3 climbR = new Vector3(oldX - (-modX), transform.position.y + GetModY(), transform.position.z);
    //        Vector3 climbL = new Vector3(oldX - (modX), transform.position.y + GetModY(), transform.position.z);

    //        if (ledgePos.x > transform.position.x)
    //        {
    //            GetComponent<Transform>().position = climbR;
    //        }
    //        else
    //        {
    //            GetComponent<Transform>().position = climbL;
    //        }
    //    } 
    //    #endregion

    //    animator.SetBool("onLedge", false);
    //    stallMovement = false;
    //}

    private float GetModY()
    {
        float grabberTop = Mathf.Abs(controller.bounds.min.y);
        float ledgeTop = Mathf.Abs(targetLedge.bounds.max.y);
        return Mathf.Abs(ledgeTop - grabberTop);
    }

    void ApplyAnimatorParam()
    {
        animator.SetFloat("moveVel", Mathf.Abs(velocity.x));

        if (wallSliding)
        {
            animator.SetBool("wallSlide", true);
        }
        if (maxSlope)
        {
            animator.SetBool("maxSlope", true);
        }
        else
            root.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }

    void ResetAnimatorParam()
    {
        if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("jump"))
        {
            animator.SetBool("jumped", false);
        }
        if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("fall"))
        {
            animator.SetBool("leap", false);
        }
        if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("trans_jumpToFall"))
        {
            animator.SetBool("jumped", false);
        }
        if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("wallSlide"))
        {
            animator.SetBool("jumped", false);
            animator.SetBool("onGround", false);
        }
        if (animator.GetBool("wallSlide") == true)
        {
            animator.SetBool("onGround", false);
        }
        if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("groundMovement"))
        {
            animator.SetBool("onGround", true);
        }
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            animator.SetBool("jumped", false);
            animator.SetBool("wallSlide", false);
        }
        if (!maxSlope)
        {
            animator.SetBool("maxSlope", false);
        }
        if (!canLeap)
        {
            animator.SetBool("leapRdy", false);
        }
        //if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("climbLedge"))
        //{
        //    if (grabber.ledge == null && grabber.targetLedge == null && !grabber.normalLedge)
        //    {
        //        Debug.LogWarning("climb anim is fired, but ledge is null");
        //        Debug.Break();
        //    }
        //    if (grabber.ledge == null && grabber.targetLedge == null && !grabber.platLedge)
        //    {
        //        Debug.LogWarning("climb anim is fired, but ledge is null");
        //        Debug.Break();
        //    }
        //}
    }

    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        float targetAngle = hit.collider.transform.localEulerAngles.z;
        float angleOutput = (float)(System.Math.Round(targetAngle, 3));

        if (angleOutput > 180)
        {
            angleOutput -= 360f; // this is necessary since some anlges are not correctly passed and be over what it should be
        }

        if (hit.normal == new Vector3(0, 1, 0))
        {
            maxSlope = false;
        }

        #region normal slope
        if (angleOutput != 0)
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(angleOutput) < controller.slopeLimit)
            {
                slopeAngle = angleOutput;
                normSlope = true;
            }
        }
        else
            normSlope = false;
        #endregion

        #region max slope detection
        if (controller.slopeLimit <= Mathf.Abs(angleOutput))
        {
            slopeAngle = angleOutput;
            slopeNormal = hit.normal;
            maxSlope = true;
        }
        #endregion

        #region wall detection
        if (controller.collisionFlags == CollisionFlags.Sides)
        {
            if (hit.normal == new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) ^ hit.normal == new Vector3(1, 0, 0))
            {
                if (hit.collider.bounds.max.y >= controller.bounds.max.y - 5f)
                {
                    if (hit.collider.bounds.size.y >= controller.bounds.size.y + 3f)
                    {
                        if (hit.gameObject.tag != "Platform")
                        {
                            Vector3 wallR = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
                            Vector3 wallL = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
                            if (hit.normal == wallR || hit.normal == wallL)
                            {
                                wallSliding = true;
                                wallDir = (hit.normal == wallR) ? 1 : -1;
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wallSliding = false;
            wallDir = 0;
        }
        #endregion

        #region slope direction detection
        if (angleOutput != 0)
        {
            //if (hit.point.x > root.transform.position.x)
            //{
            //    dirX = 1;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    dirX = -1;
            //}
            if (angleOutput > 0)
            {
                dirX = 1;
            }
            else
                dirX = -1;
        }
        #endregion

        #region platform detection
        if (hit.gameObject.GetComponent<PlatformComponent>() != null)
        {
            if (hit.gameObject.tag == "Platform")
            {
                platform = hit.gameObject;
                transform.parent = platform.transform;
                if (true)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            transform.parent = null;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Edit) Well, here's the whole script for PC movement. Ommit the GrabberListener and such since it's another class got nothing to do with current issue & movement.
On ground that is anything less slope angle than slope limit PC's velocity.y is flickering between 0 and less. I need it to stay where it stays in order to track velocity for another function. Can CharacterController just not have 100% reliable ground check? even CollisionFlag fires in mid air w/o any collidable objects nearby sometimes, so I'm not relying too much on it...

Comment: Do you get improvements if you change `public void Update()` to `FixedUpdate()`? If you have an object that has physics then all the extra movement code should go in FixedUpdate to stay in-sync with the physics engine.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Measuring! And, no. Before considering the current issue in the table I get a worse response if I use FixedUpdate (): character movement stuttering. If I coulda fixed this stuttering I'd absolutely put it in FixedUpdate () but haven't found a way.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer sensibly, since you don't show what's the order of execution of your `Move` and `ApplyGravity` methods.

Keep in mind that `controller.collisionFlags` stores the collision mask status after the last `CharacterController.Move` callback, so if you're executing `ApplyGravity` before `Move` in your `Update`, you're checking if there was a collision in the previous frame.

It could also be a problem caused by floating point approximation errors, especially with very high frame rates (`Time.deltaTime` very small), unless you've enabled Vsync.

There's maybe an useful thread you could read here: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/controller-isgrounded-doesnt-work-reliably.91436/

BTW, as a side note, why are you using everywhere

```
velocity = Method(ref velocity);
```

? It doesn't make any sense to pass an argument as a reference when you're going to store the return value to that exact same variable.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Galandil! First, I'm sorry I made it just so hard to help sharing script piece by piece. I'll fix that tmr at work. I've been coder for only recently which I'm not trying to cover up for my lacking skill, but rather trying to say not yet learned how to talk like a coder very much... So made a mistake of such on a thought I'd hate to review someone else's code that's  800 lines long.

Comment: And for the weird ref Vector's. That happened since in the unshown and will show tmr bits of code I've multiple Vector3 ouputs and Move () takes in different Vector3's for each's own movement behavior.